# Analytics referrer forum thread

Tags: google-analytics, forum, referrer, query-string

When I'm in analytics I sometimes get a referral from a forum, something like:

```
http://forums.example.com
```

Then when I click on it, it gives me a page like:

```
/viewTopic.php
```

Is there any way to get it to return the topic ID so I can click on it and see which topic it is?  At the moment I have to register, and run a search.  Can be very slow.

Comment: Can you please post a screen shot of the analytics referrer.. so we can see the full details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the [full referrer link in Google Analytics, you can add a custom filter to view the complete URL](http://techpp.com/2011/01/20/how-to-view-full-referral-link-in-google-analytics/).

If the referrer link however needs authentication, you will need to register to access that page.